# ImportError in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

I have a python project using Matplotlib. Now it is suddenly showing up following error. Previously it worked fine. I am having six 1.11 version.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `pip install six -U` for updating the version of it?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code and error messages, post the text instead directly here on SO.